# Unable to checkout PHP Google Drive Client Library

Tags: php

I have been trying to checkout the PHP Google Drive Client Library with the following url, as provided by Google documentation:

```
http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-php-client-read-only
```

When I open the repo browser with the same url, I get in but there is no directory for Drive, which explains why the above url doesnt work but I don't understand why it's missing. How else can I get the code for PHP?

Comment: How are you checking out? `svn checkout (url)`? What error do you get when doing so? Are you sure the directory you believe is missing should be in there? If you can checkout what is there, do so and run the tests - perhaps it is all present and correct?

Comment: I'm using SVN on Windows, I go to TortoiseSVN -> checkout -> enter the above url and I get a server error message saying the directory does not exist. As I said, when using the same url in the repo browser I can get in but no such directory is there

Comment: That [link](http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-api-php-client-read-only) gives me a 404.

Comment: @JosephSilber, Zachary: the link is [this](http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) - the last part after the space is a custom folder name, I think. The link works fine for me. Yes, there's no "Drive" folder in the root, but you haven't said why you are sure there should be one.

Comment: I see that in the repo browser but again, there is no Drive folder in there

Comment: because of this : https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php#step_1_enable_the_drive_api

Comment: There's nothing in step 1 that talks about such a folder, afaict. The core of it is likely to be `src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php`, which accesses your remote Google Drive for you (step 3).

Comment: so I have to use all those files to access the Google Drive API?

Comment: _All_ the files in the repo? Probably not - there seems to be a lot of files there for a lot of purposes - but when installing a library in your project, it is usual practice to include all of them. Don't modify any or delete any, unless you really know what you're doing `:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the correct repository url: http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Comment: Yup, as per my link in the comments `:)`